# Kafka connect API SourceRecord to SinkRecord transformation

Tags: apache-kafka-connect, debezium

Im using debezium embedded connector to listen to changes in database. It gives me a `ChangeEvent<SourceRecord,SourceRecord>` object.

I want to further use confluent plugin KCBQ which uses `SinkRecord` to put data to bigqery. But I'm not able to figure out how to join these two pieces.

Eventually, how do i ensure updates, deletes and schema changes from MySQL are propagated to BigQuery from Embedded Debezium

Answer (score 0):

You will possibly have to use a single message transform if you have to any custom transforms. However for this scenario , since this seems to be a commonly used transform , the extract new state transform seems to accomplish this. May be worth having a look and trying something similar

https://issues.redhat.com/browse/DBZ-226

https://issues.redhat.com/browse/DBZ-1896

Comment: Yes essentially we're looking for a mysql to bigquery source to sink transformer.... Any help will be appreciated in this regard.